# Getting predictive mode to suggest all possible environments

Tags: emacs, editors, auto-completion

I'm trying auctex+predictive mode as my new latex editor. One feature that tempted me to add predictive mode to the equation, was the feature advertised in the image below:

[image: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX]

[source](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX)

This is particularly nice for me because sometimes I forget I have certain tools in my arsenal. So I gave it a shot and the best I could get was this:

[image]

However, if I type in the first letter of the environment name, then I get suggestions:

[image]

But typing the first letter defeats the purpose which I described above. Any ideas?

P.S. Initially I intended to post this on emacs.estackexchange but I think this community would be more experienced in the matter!

Comment: For environments, in particular, I'd use AUCTeX's "C-c C-e", after that, a "TAB" should give you all possible completions. (That's not predictive mode though...)

Comment: Thanks. I know about this. Unfortunately I'm not a fan of emacs' bottom buffer constantly jumping up and down ;) That is the main reason I'm trying to achieve this via predictive mode.

Comment: I supposed so. I cannot claim much experience in the matter, for I'm also new in these waters, but I've also been playing with alternatives these days. I could get [auto-complete-auctex](https://melpa.org/#/auto-complete-auctex) to do a decent job in line with what you want (not sure if with your exact requirements, and I didn't really try predictive). However, I reached the conclusion that such a tool essentially relieves AUCTeX of what it does best. You get the right completion, but not that interaction including arguments and so on. Alternatively, you could also consider yasnippet.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, it turned out I have to set the following variable provided by `predictive-mode`:

```
(setq predictive-latex-electric-environments 1)
```